# How to get value of a table cell when selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following table, I need to get text value of cell next to selected cell, basically if `2` is clicked it needs to show me the value of cell next to it which is `eric` and so on. The table below is an example data is filled dynamically and I don't think I can give an ID to specific `<td>`.

```js
$('#inputTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var rowIndex = $(this).find('span').text();
  alert(rowIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="ui compact celled definition table" id="inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><span>Mike</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><span>eric</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><span>jonas</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Since I didn't know how to find cell next to the clicked area I used `<span>` to find the text's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a more specific selector (for example [`body tbody td:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)). This will select the *first* `<td>` element in each `<tr>`, and using `siblings()` we can select the next element in the row.

The following will work:

```js
$('#inputTable').on('click', 'tbody tr td:first-child', function(e) {  
    var text = $(this).siblings('td').find('span').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ui compact celled definition table" id="inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><span>Mike</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><span>eric</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><span>jonas</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice that you also need to close your `<span>` elements, i.e.: `<span>jonas</span>`

Comment: Hey BenM thanks man, it works but there is a problem, i think because of `td:first` it only works on first cell only.

Comment: @Valkyriee See the edit, I changed to `:first-child`.

Answer (score 1):

`tbody tr` becomes `tbody td:first-child`: if you want to attach click event to the first column only. `tr` can be omitted because you already have `tbody` to distinct it from table header rows.

`$(this).next().find('span').text()`: from the first column of the row, find the next column then get the content of its `<span>` element.

```js
$('#inputTable').on('click', 'tbody td:first-child', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var rowIndex = $(this).next().find('span').text();
  alert(rowIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="ui compact celled definition table" id="inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><span>Mike</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><span>eric</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><span>jonas</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inputTable tr').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rowIndex = $(this).find('span').text();
    alert(rowIndex);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ui compact celled definition table" id="inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><span>Mike<span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><span>eric<span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><span>jonas<span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```